# Twitter Card Not Displaying Images

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

The twitter card stopped displaying the images recently. It was working fine but the issue started three weeks ago. Nothing changed on the coding side. Tried validating the URL in twitter card validator, it validates it without any error but without any image. This is the message that I get.

twitter:card = summary tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully

After reading a few posts,

1. I tried changing the card from summary_large_image to summary. It didn't help either.
2. Instead of twitter:image, I tried twitter:image:src and it didn't help either.
3. Robots.txt is also fine. We not blocking any bots.

The article URL is different from the Image url and it is our subdomain only.
Not sure what am I missing. Any thoughts and insights would be helpful.

Thanks in advance
Sri

Comment: Is the image URL complete and valid? Is the image domain robots.txt restricting access? What is the article URL?

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet? I'm running into the same issue. Tried everything. No avail.

Answer (score 3):

What metas are you using? Perhaps one of these is missing:

```
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Here all the description" />
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://website/pathname/filename.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="400" />
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="300" />
```

Comment: How does this not have more upvotes. Thanks so much, first solution that worked for me.

Comment: Things that happen

Answer (score -1):

When I dealt with a twitter card image validation problem, the image wasn't pulling, the image needed to be whatever.jpeg not whatever.jpg

Comment: There are actually no differences between the JPG and JPEG formats. The only difference is the number of characters used. JPG only exists because they required a three-letter extension for the file names in earlier versions of Windows (MS-DOS 8.3 and FAT-16 file systems)